# Alternative for jackson-databind

Tags: jackson-databind

Due to security vulnerability, Our organization has requested us to not use jackson-databind in our applications and please let me know if there is any other alternative jar we can use instead of jackson-databind.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the request size, for small JSON files you can use GSON library, for bigger files JSON.simple library has better perfomance.
You can find a comparison in here: https://blog.overops.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/